# Flex iOS app cannot start without internet connection and then shows unwanted popup

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I am writing an app for iOS using flex. I am deep into development.

This morning one of my testers reported seeing a flex based popup that I did not create.

I am not able to post pictures here but to describe the popup - It has a grey header-bar with a small close button which looks more like a flex panel. As far as I'm aware this is not part of the standard flex popup. It then has a question mark image in the top left corner of the main window. I believe this is the stand in graphic that flex uses when it tried to load an image but can't. At the bottom of the popup is a text input box which is pre-filled with an IP address. The address is the same for both myself and the tester. Finally at the very bottom is an OK and a Cancel button.

The buttons are styled because I set a global button skin for my app. Other than that I did not create this popup and cannot find any evidence of it in my scripts.

I immediately fired up the same build that I have on my own iPad. I had tested it before sending out and had not seen any evidence of this before but when I tested it this morning, I too saw this popup. It seems to have literally occurred overnight.

I did some more testing and have discovered that if I turn off all internet connections then the app won't even start. It hangs at the splash screen. I can't be certain about this build but I know that previous builds have most definitely worked offline.

I have searched all through my scripts for something that might cause this. I am not using any reference libraries beyond the standard ones and I'm not using any ANE's. I have also checked other Flex apps that I am working on but they all seem fine.

Has anyone else come across this before? Any ideas on what to look for or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Jamie

Comment: Ok so I don't have enough rep to answer my question yet but I've written my answer out so to save me doing it again here it is: Well it turns out that it was being caused by Flash Builders Network Monitor tool (ironic as I was trying to use this to help me figure out the cause of the problem!).

I has switched it on to help me solve a different issue yesterday. It never occurred to me that I would need to switch it off again.

I just had to disable the tool before publishing and problems all gone.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're distributing the debug version of the app and this pop-up is asking for information on how to connect to a running Flex Debugger session.  This will happen before the app runs.  You can always hit cancel to ignore it.

When distributing your app to users; I strongly recommend creating a formal release build which will not include the "Debugging" bits and therefore this pop-up will never show.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have seen what you are describing and this wasn't the same. I have figured it out though and, to be honest, it was almost just as silly of me anyway. I will post the answer.